# PowerShell 2.0 - Assigning a number to results in a formatted table

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I probably have just been at this too long today and need a mental break. Regardless I will ask anyway. I want to be able to select the number from the results below when presenting the information at a prompt

`$wsearch = '*John*'`

## Clear variables

`Remove-Variable query -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Variable num -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

## Get user search information and format table with sequential numbers

`$query = @{Expression={$num};Label="Num";width=3}, @{Expression={$_.AccountName};Label="AccountName";width=28}, @{Expression={$_.LoginID};Label="LoginID";width=24}, @{Expression={$_.Enabled};Label="Enabled";width=8}`

## Next get search results and place into Array for formatting above

`$global:num = 0; Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $wcsearch} | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Enabled | Sort-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName | Select @{Label = "Num"; Expression = {$global:num; $global:num++;}}, @{Label = "AccountName"; Expression = {$_.Name}}, @{Label = "LoginID"; Expression = {$_.SamAccountName}}, Enabled |`

## Finally send results to the screen

`Format-Table $query;`

## Ask which user to select from the results above

`Read-Host "LoginID/Num (e.g. john.d.smith or 1)"`

LoginID works fine but of course the `1` does not work since the code is not there to handle it, that is what I want to be able to accomplish here. Any help in getting that going would be great. Thanks Folks :)

---

**Here is what I have now based on the below update, yet I still need to figure out how to nullify the results and allow for me to customize what the end user sees.** Also currently only the first user found is selected all others do not work.

```
Remove-Variable query -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Variable num -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-CHost "`nPlease select from `'*green*LoginID*`' or `'*green*Num*`' from the list."
    Write-CHost "`nIf the desired results are not listed above, type '*green*m*' or '*green*menu*' to return to the *green*Main Menu*."
    $query = @{Expression={$_.num};Label="Num";width=3}, @{Expression={$_.AccountName};Label="AccountName";width=28}, @{Expression={$_.LoginID};Label="LoginID";width=24}, @{Expression={$_.Enabled};Label="Enabled";width=8}
    $global:num=1
    $Results = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $wcsearch} | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Enabled | Sort-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName | Select @{Label = "Num"; Expression = {$global:num; $global:num++;}}, @{Label = "AccountName"; Expression = {$_.Name}}, @{Label = "LoginID"; Expression = {$_.SamAccountName}}, Enabled
    Do{
        $Results | Format-Table $query
        $aduser = Read-Host "LoginID/Num (e.g. john.d.smith or 1)"
        Switch($aduser){
            {$Results.Get($Results.LoginID).LoginID -icontains $aduser} {$Results | ?{$_.LoginID -match $aduser};Continue}
            {$Results.Get($Results.num).num -icontains $aduser} {$Results | ?{$_.num -eq $aduser};Continue}
            default {Write-Host "`nError: Selection not found.`n`nPlease select from `'LoginID`' or `'Num`' from the list."}
        }
    }
    Until(($Results.Get($Results.LoginID).LoginID -icontains $aduser) -or ($Results.Get($Results.num).num -contains $aduser) -or ($aduser -eq "menu") -or ($aduser -eq "m"))
    $aduser = $Results.Get($Results.LoginID).LoginID
    write-host $aduser
    if (($aduser -eq "m") -or ($aduser -eq "menu")){
        Write-CHost "`nUser *red*Cancelled*, Going back to the *green*Main Menu*"
        Start-Sleep 2
        cleanScreen
        showMainMenu
    }
```

Comment: I wrote a function for that once...http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Select-Item-V-10-beta-5e579fa6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to capture the results to an array, then display that array and have the user pick from the options presented so that you have something to match their selection against.

```
$query = @{Expression={$_.num};Label="Num";width=3}, @{Expression={$_.AccountName};Label="AccountName";width=28}, @{Expression={$_.LoginID};Label="LoginID";width=24}, @{Expression={$_.Enabled};Label="Enabled";width=8}
$num=0
$Results = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $wcsearch} | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Enabled | Sort-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName | Select @{Label = "Num"; Expression = {$global:num; $global:num++;}}, @{Label = "AccountName"; Expression = {$_.Name}}, @{Label = "LoginID"; Expression = {$_.SamAccountName}}, Enabled
Do{
    $Results | FT $query
    $i = Read-Host "LoginID/Num (e.g. john.d.smith or 1)"
    Switch($i){
        {$Results.LoginID -icontains $i} {$Results | ?{$_.LoginID -match $i};Continue}
        {$Results.num -icontains $i} {$Results | ?{$_.num -eq $i};Continue}
        default {Write-Host "`n`nSelection not found.`nPlease select LoginID or Num from the list" -ForegroundColor Red}
    }
}Until(($Results.LoginID -icontains $i) -or ($Results.num -contains $i))
```

**Edit:** Sounds like you need a better solution than displaying a table and having the user select a name or number. Perhaps you should output to a GridView and have the user select from there. That way the GridView disappears once the user selects an option, and gives them a simple way to select. In that case you would do something like this:

```
$num=0
$Results = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $wcsearch} | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Enabled | Sort-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName | Select @{Label = "Num"; Expression = {$global:num; $global:num++;}}, @{Label = "AccountName"; Expression = {$_.Name}}, @{Label = "LoginID"; Expression = {$_.SamAccountName}}, Enabled
$i=""
Do{
    $i=$Results | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single

}While(!$i)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Got me headed in the right direction. Now I had to change it up a little. Updated above. One more thing. I tried to make the results not show once a selection is made but each time I attempt to it clears the results making them null. How would this best be handled?

Comment: So on the next line just clear the screen (`Clear-Host` or `cls`). Also, I don't see anything above updated.

Comment: This set of code is in the middle of a function in a script. Clearing the screen means clearing information the client needs to see. I need to find another way to do it. I also updated your post with my changes, it seems to have disappeared. I am going to update the above post with what I have now.

Comment: "-OutputMode Single" is not a valid option. I am using PowerShell 2.0 due to environment restrictions.

Comment: To be fair I did answer your original question. In my opinion you should accept the answer and then open a new question for managing what data is displayed to the user, and removing sensitive data once a choice is made.

Comment: I would accept if I could (just a newbie here on stack) and I do really appreciate your help.